# Closing the lid locks the screen

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

Is there anyway of making the MacBook Pro lock the screen when I close the lid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. Apple menu (top left) → System Preferences → Security → General tab. It's the first checkbox *Require password [time] after sleep or screen saver begins* where [time] is immediately or higher.